# Create conan package without copying sources

Tags: conan

I have a rather large code base of ~400MB consisting of 46k files (historical reasons). Calling `conan create` takes over 15 min and is mostly copying files. Calling cmake directly only takes ~20s.

I now want to disable copying with no_copy_source, but cmake can't find the source files unless I pass an absolute path.

What am I missing?

```
class MyConan(ConanFile):
    generators = "cmake"
    no_copy_source = True

    def build(self):
        cmake = CMake(self)
        # What do I need to pass so that it works?
        # cmake.configure(source_dir="D:/git/mysources/") would work
        cmake.configure()
        cmake.build()

    def package(self):
        self.copy("*.lib", dst="lib", keep_path=False)
        self.copy("*.dll", dst="bin", keep_path=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing nothing.

The attribute [no-copy-source](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/conanfile/attributes.html#no-copy-source) tells to Conan don't copy any file to build folder. When you runs `conan create`, Conan will build all files from build_folder. That's why cmake is not able to find those files.

As you have a big repository, you need to pass the source folder to CMake configure:

```py
def _configure_cmake(self):
    cmake = CMake()
    cmake.configure(source_dir=self.source_folder)
    return cmake

def build(self):
    cmake = self._configure_cmake()
    cmake.build()

def package(self):
    # if cmake file has install() configured
    cmake = self._configure_cmake()
    cmake.install()

    # of copy directly
    self.copy("*.lib", dst="lib", src=os.path.join(self.source_folder, "lib"))
```

As you can see, the source folder is now configured properly, including when packaging.

Comment: The problem with this is, that self.source_folder is pointing to `C:/Users/myuser/.conan/data/mypackage/1.0/user/stable/source` instead of `D:/git/mysources/`. Therefore the cmake command fails rightfully with `CMake Error: The source directory "C:/Users/myuser/.conan/data/mypackage/1.0/user/stable/source" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.`

Comment: So you are not copying your project to source_folder, by `source()` method. In this case, you should follow the development flow: https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/developing_packages/package_dev_flow.html You will need to run step-by-step.